# What is the best time to exercise

Tags: health

So, after starting to gain weight on sitting in front of my computer too long, I have decided to take the plunge and maybe stick to an exercise regimen. As has been reported by [some studies](http://www.doctoroz.com/videos/what-s-best-time-exercise), exercising in the morning can be more beneficial than doing so in the evening. Now, personally, waking up in the morning is a huge chore for me. Furthermore, I have people advising me to hit the loo (toilet) before exercising as it may not be good for my health and leads to waste accumulation in the body. Now, search as I may, I cant find any basis that supports this theory. I understand that hygiene might be a factor but does exercising in the morning before going to the loo have any effects on health in general? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WHO's definition about Health

> Health is a state of complete physical, mental and social well-being and not merely the absence of disease or infirmity.

In other words, Good health means active life where you can express yourself freely, you can succeed and can make mistakes, can reach your goals, can understand your body and others, and can say **no** when you see your limit to yourself and others - and can set new targets to yourself, feel accepted in your society and accept **yourself** as you are.

### Best time to Exercise for successful results in competitions - dependent on Age

- Endurance atletes during ages 25-30 years in this answer about [Why does max heart rate decrease with age?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/19268/86)

### Short-term and long-term effects of exercise on Vitality

There are many stages in your question in Physiology, Pathophysiology and Microbiology, for instance.
I can cover here only the surface:

- very short effect of short exercise (20 min) on brain
- long term effect of regular short exercise (20 min) on brain, hypothalamus and biologic clock - wakefulness (limbic system)
- long-term effect of regular weekly exercise (3.5 h) on brain
- long-term effect of regular weekly exercise (3.5 h) on body muscles
- long-term effect of careful regular stretching and appropriate resting on congestion of body
- long-term effect of regular weekly exercise (3.5 h) on metabolism
- effect of regular exercise on circulation system (blood and lymph) - known to increase i.e. include temperature distribution and defence bodies distribution
- short-term effect of short exercise on PTH secretion (calcium); autoregulation of renal blood flow with two major theories: myogenic mechanism and tubuloglomerular effect

where I only briefly cover one term in Pathology.
There are two unanswered questions about the renal function [Costanzo, 2013]

> (1) What component of tubular fluid is sensed at the macula densa? The
>   major candidates are luminal Na+ and Cl−. (2) What vasoactive
>   substance is secreted by the juxtaglomerular apparatus to act locally
>   on afferent arterioles? Here, the candidates are adenosine, ATP, and
>   thromboxane.

so to understand the effect of short-term morning training on PTH secretion, we should understand the two questions first.

### Evidences to some things

[image]

Short-term exercise can work sometimes as prophylactics for allergic symptoms.
I think the most important thing is the irritation of your skin which is the most important endocrine organ in our body.
Skin's temperature change secretes many hormones than help us to stand irritations from the environment.

What are the effects of short-term exercise in the morning depends on the patient at hand.
I cannot say much general.
For instance, if your heart is not strained; that it has too high T peak, too heavy exercise can cause you harm.

**My personal experience**

- Short-term exercise suited to a person with no deficits in sleeping can help to alleviate symptoms of allergies and decrease stress in a normally physiological balances without viral infections,

but the real world is not that nice.
The problem comes if the patient has any disease that uses our immune system against us such as some **viral infection**.
The immune response is also the source of pathogenesis for many viral diseases.
Unlike for a bacterial infection, the ultimate goal of the immune response in a viral infection is to eliminate both the virus and the host cells harbouring or replicating the virus, [Murray, Medical Microbiology, 6th ed].
Actually, some drugs are immunosuppressant like cortisone, and some procedures like radiation therapy.

However, with some medication plans, you should avoid drugs, living styles and habits that immunosuppresses your body. 
For instance, HIV patients with HAART medication plan (medication combination is antiretroviral but possible immunosuppressive pathways may exist in different conditions) that involves a strategy depending on the condition, since HAART medications are life-long and cannot be stop, so other conditions etc TBC must be treated first, to avoid too much burden on the body at the same time.
In a similar way, avoiding living style or habits that puts immunosystem down can help with HIV.
Doing sport when you have slept badly many days and feel exhausted, puts your body under immunosuppression. 
So the state of the disease or your physical wellbeing determines when sport is useful and when not.

**Other part of your question**

To hit toiled before exercise is good because then

- you decrease the risk of gastrointestinal bleeding and venous congestion.
- effect of exercise on constipation is one topic here; depends on you, since there are many types

The more stuff you have in your colon and gastrointestinal system, the harder it is to use fully your muscles of your body. 
Try pull-ups with more empty colon vs full one.
Pull-ups require many muscles from upper trunk and lower trunk. 
You cannot use all your stomach muscles if something is blocking your middle body muscles.

Good Hygiene is the easiest way to decrease the risk of any infections caused by many factors.
I estimate that 2-5 % of people visiting public toilets wash hands correctly; one video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0at_jtzJCDM) about how one should do it.
Many people leave their hands wet.
If you have infection in your body, you should not exercise because failure to resolve the infection may lead to persistent or chronic infection or death.
It takes much energy from our body to handle with infections.
To recover from training, it requires good balance of many factors.

### Summary

The best time to do sport when you are healthy

- you do not have any infections (viral particularly) because a failure to resolve the infection can lead to persistent or chronic infection or death
- when you have prepared early enough for the exercise with enough sleep

where pathologies and/or teratologies are not limiting your process.
You compete only against yourself and then grow from that to see you how good person you are really.

The morning exercise in a body which has rested well before the exercise and prepared accordingly to the exercise can be useful because

- short-term effects on the brain (process things during exercise) (See Figure 1)
- possible short-term effects during day after the exercise

and if the exercise becomes a habit in a healthy person, then

- long-term effects: increased metabolism and many other positive effects described above
- and many other possible reasons from social to better self-esteem

when the the person listens to his body and stops when it hurts or something goes over; can rest accordingly.
Good motivation is useful in gaining good health.
Motivation is the strength and direction of the effort.
If you are interested in morning exercise, then you can set target and make a realistic plan.
Listen your own body and be able to refit your plan accordingly.
Actually, here is an important step that the consultation of many doctors can be useful; one doctor cannot always see the main problem for instance of prolonged and deepened allergic symptoms.
Consultation and discussions of other people can also be useful - like discussing where to help for this and this; who has enough capabilities to understand it.
The person cannot always know himself what is a main disease underneath.
Anything can come that postpone some training sessions.

Sources

1. Infectious disease courses 2015-2016
2. Gleeson. [The effect on immunity of long-term intensive training in elite swimmers](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1553334/).
3. Anderson. [Effects of Exercise and Physical Activity on Anxiety](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3632802/). 2013.
4. Laires. [Exercise, magnesium and immune function](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18705536).
5. Gunzer. [Exercise-Induced Immunodepression in Endurance Athletes and Nutritional Intervention with Carbohydrate, Protein and Fat—What Is Possible, What Is Not?](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3475230/)
6. HAART and HIV in DynaMed Plus. Visited 7.8.2016.
7. WHO. [Health Education](http://www.who.int/topics/health_education/en/). Visited 7.8.2016.
8. ...

Comment: Can you please add references to your answer? Especially the first part about exercising and and allegies needs this.

Comment: @Chris To investigate such a thing is very difficult in a general subject. I need more specific patient data to give references: sleeping rhythm, age, gender, training history, allergies, blood picture etc to give exact references. Otherwise, the scope of this answer cannot be reached in a lifetime. Please, say exactly to which statement you want a reference so it is easier for me to find it. There are very many sources which I have used in my text. Please, specify what is your exact interest here.

Comment: This is not hard - you claim that exercising improves the symptoms of allergies. To do so, there should be some studies proving it. If these do not exist, than you can simply not claim this. If this is your experience than this is anecdotal and also no proof.

Comment: Your post could still do with references for it's points, particularly: "Short-term exercise can work sometimes as prophylactics for allergic symptoms".  HIV treatment is also not by immunosuppresant drugs (this is what you are trying to avoid).  There has been some very limited research into trialling immune suppression but clinically it's treated with HAART - antivirals not immune suppressors.